# How to efficiently deal with LAS tile overlap when 'Classify LAS Overlap' takes days

Tags: arcgis-pro, lidar, 3d-analyst, lasd

I am using the tool 'Classify LAS Overlap' in ArcGIS Pro to classify overlap points in LIDAR data from multiple sources (data from Colorado Hazard Mapping) in order to eventually turn them into a cohesive DSM. I need to do this with a large number of tiles, but running the tool on an LASD with just two tiles takes at least 12 hours. Using this on dozens of tiles seems unrealistic. Is there any other approach I can take in order to deal with overlapping LAS tiles?